# Custom syntax file for FIX data doesn't work

Tags: syntax-highlighting, regular-expression

I tried to create a custom syntax file to read [FIX messages](http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/). Note: [I am certain my custom files are being loaded by Vim.](https://superuser.com/questions/763121/cygwin-vim-doesnt-load-files-in-runtimepath)

The file format is sequences of `NUMBER=VALUE` pairs separated by the unprintable `0x1` character. I wanted a few of the pairs (the ones with important data) to turn colors when I open the file in Vim. I don't care about which colors they turn, as long as they are all different and are easily distinguishable from each other.

Specifically, I want the tags associated with the following numbers to be highlighted: 44, 52, 54, 60, 9717.

Here's my syntax file (`~/.vim/syntax.vim`)

```
if version >= 600
    if exists("b:current_syntax")
         finish
    endif
else
    syntax clear
endif

syn case ignore

"syn match fixPrice "\|44[=][^|]\+\|"
"syn match fixSendingTime "\|52[=][^|]\+\|"
"syn match fixTransactTime "\|60[=][^|]\+\|"
"syn match fixCorrelation "\|9717[=][^|]\+\|"
"syn match fixSide "\|54[=][^|]\+\|"
syn match fixPrice "44"
syn match fixSendingTime "|52"
syn match fixTransactTime "\|60"
syn match fixCorrelation "\|9717"
syn match fixSide "\|54"

" Define the default highlighting
if version >= 508 || !exists("did_fix_syntax_inits")
        if version < 508
                let did_fix_syntax_inits = 1
                command -nargs=+ HiLink hi link <args>
        else
                command -nargs=+ HiLink hi def link <args>
        endif

        HiLink fixPrice Label
        HiLink fixSendingTime Number
        HiLink fixTransactTime Include
        HiLink fixCorrelation String
        HiLink fixSide Identifier

        delcommand HiLink
endif

let b:current_syntax = "fix"
```

Sample line of data:

```
8=FIXT.1.1^A9=380^A35=X^A49=CME^A56=0^A34=13362975^A52=20130626135401572^A1128=9^A268=3^A279=0^A269=2^A48=42025^A22=8^A270=-224^A271=1^A273=135401000^A274=2^A451=32^A1020=23^A83=523628^A5799=1^A5797=1^A279=0^A269=2^A48=17311^A22=8^A270=12356^A271=1^A273=135401000^A277=1^A451=-395^A1020=201377^A83=5671131^A5797=1^A279=0^A269=2^A48=122816^A22=8^A270=12580^A271=1^A273=135401000^A274=2^A277=1^A451=-427^A1020=31^A83=1396693^A5797=2^A75=20130626^A10=001^A
```

Note that the `^A` characters are the `0x1` unprintable characters, you can fix this file with:

```
:%s/\^A/<01>/
```

Where `<01>` is entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> followed by <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

This should work, note that `<01>` is *not* literal text, it is the 0x01 character. You can enter it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> followed by <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>.

```
if exists("b:current_syntax")
        finish
endif

syn case ignore

syn match fixPrice         "<01>44=[^<01>]*"
syn match fixSendingTime   "<01>52=[^<01>]*"
syn match fixSide          "<01>54=[^<01>]*"
syn match fixTransactTime  "<01>60=[^<01>]*"
syn match fixCorrelation   "<01>9717=[^<01>]*"

hi def link fixPrice         Label
hi def link fixSendingTime   Number
hi def link fixSide          Identifier
hi def link fixTransactTime  Include
hi def link fixCorrelation   String

let b:current_syntax = "fix"
```

If you copy/pasted it, you can fix it up with: `:%s/<01>/<01>/g`, where the first `<01>` is literal text, and the *second* is the 0x01 character.

The regexp explained:

- `<01>` - match 0x01 character
- `44=` - followed by your 'magic' number and a `=` sign
- `[^<01>]*` - followed by 0 or more of any character *except* the 0x01 character.

You could maybe make the text stand out more by using bold text, or different background colours. But I'll leave that up to you ;-)

I removed all of the legacy cruft for *very*, *very* old Vim versions. You don't need it.

Screenshot:

[image]